# Create my own listener using lambdas

Tags: android, kotlin

What I want to archive in my activity/fragment

```
 adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item ->
          //do smt with item
        }
```

What I'm setting up in the adapter but no luck:

```
private var listener: OnItemClickListener?=null  

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
     val item = getItem(position)
     item?.let { holder.bindView(it) }
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { item?.let { listener?.onItemClick(it) } }
     }

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Item) -> Unit){
    this.listener = listener as OnItemClickListener //this will throw type cast error
    }
```

EDIT 1: should I use 2 types along side for the same work like below?

```
private var lambdaListener: ((Item) -> Unit)? = null

private var listener: OnItemClickListener?=null  

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        item?.let { holder.bindView(it) }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            item?.let { listener?.onItemClick(it) }
            item?.let { it1 -> lambdaListener?.invoke(it1) }
        }
    }

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Item) -> Unit) {
        lambdaListener = listener
}
```

How android-kotlin-extensions can create the lambda expression like: `view.setOnClickListener{view -> //do smt }`
or even

```
view.setOnClickListener{//do smt }
```

EDIT FINAL:
Thank for the marked correct answer, It isn't really solved the problem but gives me this idea:

```
this.listener = object : OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(item: Item) = listener(item)
    }
```

with OnItemClickListener is still a kotlin interface, no need to rewrite it to java interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda is not suitable to cast to the `OnItemClickListener` interface. You'll have to implement the interface manually and call the function in there. To improve the implementation, you can also use the `inline` feature with it.

```
inline fun setOnItemClickListener(crossinline listener: (Item) -> Unit) {
    this.listener = OnItemClickListener { listener(it) }
}
```

This will work if `OnItemClickListener` is a *Java* interface. If it's a *Kotlin* interface, you'd have to implement it with the `object` notation.

```
inline fun setOnItemClickListener(crossinline listener: (Item) -> Unit) {
    this.listener = object : OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(item: Item) = listener(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I meant with the last sentence... Why did you have to remove the `crossinline`?

Answer (score 4):

> How android-kotlin-extensions can create the lambda expression like: `view.setOnClickListener{view -> //do smt }` or even `view.setOnClickListener{//do smt }`

Kotlin has [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). `view.setOnClickListener{//do smt }` works because there is a default name `it` for single paramter method.

> This means that Kotlin function literals can be automatically converted into implementations of Java interfaces with a single non-default method, as long as the parameter types of the interface method match the parameter types of the Kotlin function.

Current only Java interface support SAM Conversions. See [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770) for further discussion.

To work around this problem, one way is to wrap the lambda yourself.

```
fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Item) -> Unit) {
    listener = OnItemClickListener { listener.invoke(it) }
}
```

Comment: fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Item) -> Unit) {
    listener = OnItemClickListener { listener.invoke(it) }
}

It doesn't work. AS show: interface does not have constructors. Following the answer above, if we do smt like this, OnItemClickListener must be written by java

Comment: @Slim_user71169 I assumed you are create a wrapper type class. If you are accepting a listener, unless you need to identify which class is a listener, I think just accept lambda would be much cleaner.

Comment: Should I forget the java's approach? anw, I found a mixed way in my edited post

Comment: @Slim_user71169 Do you have to test a class being `OnItemClickListener`? If no and its pure purpose is to pass a method, then there is no need to create a interface for that.

Comment: It's just:
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(item: Item)
}